# Playing wildcard (Jacks or multiples of a role) for a role which I have in hand

Tags: glory-to-rome

In Glory to Rome, is there any rule prohibiting players from playing wildcards if I have the role in hand? For example, can I play three (or two, depending on the cardset used) laborers and call that a laborer wild card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no restriction on wildcarding that I have seen. It can be, in fact, a good idea if you need a particular ability to use a jack instead for the role, so that you can then play the card itself onto a foundation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can play three Laborers as a Jack, to lead or follow the Labor action. It's a bit silly, but it gets several cards into the pool, it empties your hand, and it'll amuse everyone at the table.

With a little luck, your next Thinker action will get you more useful cards, and perhaps you can Merchant some of that Rubble into your Vault. This is particularly tempting if you can't think of anything to do with all of those Laborers in your hand. (On a side note, if your play group likes to keep the pool empty, then the Bar is particularly handy for picking up clients.)